# Generics with default parameters get an error

Tags: typescript

typescript Generics with default parameters get an error

```
function func <T> (name: T = 'test'): T {
  return name;
}
```

get an error

how to fix it;

Comment: Please add details on the error you found. How it occurs? What is the error message? so that we can help you on the problem.

Comment: why not skip default value and set name to 'test' if name is null, inside method?

Answer (score 1):

> how to fix it

Add that value to the type e.g.

```
function func<T>(name: T | 'test' = 'test'): T | 'test' {
    return name;
}
```